# Is it okay to have multiple Dispatcher.BeginInvoke?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, binding, wcf-binding

I am just a starter in silverlight and WCF. I came across a very good article "http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/11/Understanding-WCF-Services-in-Silverlight-2" by Miguel A. Castro which teaches to add the WCF manually.

In the example, it uses Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to write the text return by the service into a textblock in silverlight UI.

```
       AsyncCallback asyncCallBack = delegate(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            List<Person> person = ((IPersonService_list)result.AsyncState).EndGetPersonData(result);
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
            {
                spMain.Children.Add(new TextBlock
                {
                    Text = person[0].FirstName + person[0].LastName + person[0].City + person[0].State
                });

            });
        };
```

I need to populate more than one control using the same service. It seems I am not allow to call another function within the BeginInvoke method. Is the best way to have multiple BeginInvoke method? Will that consume a lot of resources?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that would work:  Build an enclosing `UIElement` structure in its entirety from the results of the WCF service call, then use one call to `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` and add the structure to `spMain` `UIElement`. For example:

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
TextBlock tb1 = new TextBlock({
    Text=person[0].FirstName + person[0].LastName
});
sp.Children.Add(tb1);
TextBlock tb2 = new TextBlock({Text="AND SO ON Use this pattern to add UIElements to the stackpanel."});

sp.Children.add(tb2);

//now - add the StackPanel which holds other UIElements to spMain.

this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate(){
    spMain.Children.Add( sp );
});
```